# What causes Composer not to update to a, modified, existing version?

Tags: php, composer-php, version

I've created a v1.0.4 tag for my plug-in and deployer executed `composer update` on the server. After a short amount of time I've deleted this tag and created it again because this version needed a minor modification.
Now when deployer executes `composer update` on the server the plug-in is not been updated to the new v1.0.4 (that includes the modification) because the version number is still the same.

I've executed `composer clear-cache` on the server but this does not seem to work. Is this even possible or was it better to create a new version for this modification?

The modified tag v1.0.4 is present in the repository. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please tag your plugin properly as a new version. If v1.0.4 of it is already installed, the commit hash used by that tag is stored in `composer.lock`, and getting this fixed might lead to more problems popping up.